# evaluate a string using a different object as the global

Tags: javascript, eval, global

Is there any way, using pure javascript, to do something like the following?

```
var x = 12;
var subGlobal = {};
evalInGlobal(subGlobal, "x = 100;");

console.log(x); //--> 12
console.log(subGlobal.x); //--> 100
```

The rationale is that I'd like to run scripts in isolated environments, so each script can be referring to an `x` yet have that `x` be different (for example).

Comment: Initially `eval` accepted two parameters, the string to be evaluated and the environment. Since with this definiton there was no *safe scope*(ie the actual JS's **private variables**) it has been removed. No, there is no way of doing this without attempting to write something like a new (simple) compiler.

Comment: @LightStyle: Hmm I suppose it would be easy enough.. find all unbound variables, prepend them with `__tmpglobal.`, then evaluate the string `var __tmpglobal = (subGlobal); %s; delete __tmpglobal`. Was hoping there was an easier way.. luckily for now I'm embedding spidermonkey so I simply bound a call to `JS_EvaluateScript` but I'm gonna have to make a browser version of this app at some point

Comment: Assigning `window.eval` to a variable and then using the variable as `eval()`, [executes](http://jsfiddle.net/YZ9Yc/) its argument in the global scope, nevertheless what the current scope is. Though this is more like a reverse of what you need?

Comment: @Teemu: that's not quite it, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears what I'm going to do is do a 100% JavaScript approach by using [esprima](http://esprima.org/) to parse the code, modifying the parse tree by replacing root var declarations and unbound variable assignments with assignments to a property of `__thisglobal`, then regenerating the script using [escodegen](https://github.com/Constellation/escodegen) and running it. Will see how it goes.

EDIT: It worked! Now it turns stuff like this:

```
window.addSprite("Logo--oceanGamesLabel", Text("arial.ttf", [112, 112, 255], "Ocean Games"));

// ------------------- labels ----------------------
function labelText(text, halign) {
    halign = halign || "right";
    return Text("arial.ttf", [255, 255, 255], text,
        halign, "center", "labels");
}
window.addSprite("Inputs--usernameLabel", labelText("Username: "));
window.addSprite("Inputs--passwordLabel", labelText("Password: "));
```

Into stuff like this:

```
/*-!-OGGlobalified-!-*/
(function ($$GLOBAL) { 
    return (function ($$GLOBAL) {
        {
            $$GLOBAL.TESTING = false;
        }
        $$GLOBAL.console.logf('login.init.js running on window %s(%s)', $$GLOBAL.window.name, $$GLOBAL.window.handle);
        $$GLOBAL.window.addSprite('Logo--oceanGamesLabel', $$GLOBAL.Text('arial.ttf', [
            112,
            112,
            255
            ], 'Ocean Games'));
        {
            $$GLOBAL.labelText = function (text, halign) {
                $$GLOBAL.halign = $$GLOBAL.halign || 'right';
                return $$GLOBAL.Text('arial.ttf', [
                    255,
                    255,
                    255
                    ], $$GLOBAL.text, $$GLOBAL.halign, 'center', 'labels');
            };
        }
        $$GLOBAL.window.addSprite('Inputs--usernameLabel', $$GLOBAL.labelText('Username: '));
        $$GLOBAL.window.addSprite('Inputs--passwordLabel', $$GLOBAL.labelText('Password: '));
    }).apply($$GLOBAL, [$$GLOBAL]);
})
```

That is, it returns a string which evaluates to a function that can then be called with a global object of choice. And it does scoping properly and such. Fun stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I can get is this.  It requires initializing the set of variables of `global` used in `code` beforehand.

```
var evalInGlobal = function(global, code) {
    global.x = null; // this is necessary
    with(global) { 
        eval(code); 
    };
};
var x = 12;
var subGlobal = {};
evalInGlobal(subGlobal, "x = 100;");

console.log(x); //--> 12
console.log(subGlobal.x); //--> 100
```

To get rid of the initialization, I think you have to translate the code block to something aware of a scope. For example, translate `x = 100;` to `function(ctx) { ctx.x = 100; }` and invoke it by calling `fn(global)`.

That is similar to the way AngularJS builds [their parser](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L898-L919) to allow expressions (a small subset of JS) evaluated against a given scope.

Comment: interesting, didn't think of the `with` keyword. still seems i'd have to end up writing a scope analyzer to automatically modify those scripts though..

Comment: @Claudiu I think so, if you know the set of variables in advanced, just initialize them on `global` in a loop. If not and if you can define certain naming conventions for those variables, you can extract them from the code and again, set them in a loop. If that's still not allowed, then writing a translation is inevitable, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I'll agree with @LightStyle 's comment above. You could, however, do something like this, which probably isn't exactly what you want.

```
var x = 12;
var subGlobal = function() {};
subGlobal.x = undefined;

function m() {
    this.x = 100;
}

m.apply(subGlobal);

console.log(x); //--> 12
console.log(subGlobal.x); //--> 100
```